# Free space and scales in ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm interested in facet plots which would have both free scales (because units of different facet groups are different) and variable facet width or height (because different facets have different numbers of observations plotted in them). Currently, I'm able to achieve either goal but not both. Here's a minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse)
        
sample_data <- data.frame(outcome = rep(letters[1:6], 2),
                          value = rep(c(1:2, 100*1:4), 2),
                          units = rep(c("days", "days", "pax", "pax", "pax", "pax"), 2),
                          year = rep(2020:2021, each = 6)) 

p <- ggplot(sample_data, aes(x = outcome, y = value)) + geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

Using `facet_grid` and the `space = "free"` option, I'm able to get the variable facet dimensions:

```
p + facet_grid(units~year, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

Using `facet_wrap` and the `scales = "free"` option, I'm able to get the variable units.

```
p + facet_wrap(units~year, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Any idea how to get both variable facet size and free scales (preferably with the facet header structure of facet_grid)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `independent` argument in `ggh4x::facet_grid2()` to achieve this. Note that you cannot have both free axes and independent scales in the same dimension.

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample_data <- data.frame(outcome = rep(letters[1:6], 2),
                          value = rep(c(1:2, 100*1:4), 2),
                          units = rep(c("days", "days", "pax", "pax", "pax", "pax"), 2),
                          year = rep(2020:2021, each = 6)) 

ggplot(sample_data, aes(x = value, y = outcome)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(
    units ~ year,
    scales = "free", space = "free_y",
    independent = "x"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Disclaimer: I wrote ggh4x.

Comment: super helpful, thanks!